# Gradle task order in Android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have problems with the order of depending tasks in my Android project.

This is part of my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
task release

task archiveRelease(type: Copy) {
    println 'copy apk and mapping files'
    from './build/outputs/'
    into "../releases/${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_code}_${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_name}"
    include('apk/release/app-release.apk', 'mapping/release/mapping.txt')
    rename('app-release.apk', "${rootProject.ext.configuration.package}_${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_code}_${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_name}.apk")
    rename('mapping.txt', "mapping_${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_code}_${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_name}.txt")
}

project.afterEvaluate {

    dependencyUpdates.dependsOn clean
    assembleRelease.dependsOn clean

    archiveRelease.mustRunAfter("assembleRelease")
    release.dependsOn assembleRelease
}
```

But when I start the `release` task it prints `copy apk and mapping files` at the beginning and not at the end of `assembleRelease`. This is the console output:

```
$ ./gradlew release
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
copy apk and mapping files
```

How to get `archiveRelease` executed after the build is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger the build when calling release task with the following :

- `./gradlew release` : build => archiveRelease => release
- `./gradlew build` : build => archiveRelease => release

gradle :

```
task(release) {
    doLast {
        println 'release task'
    }
}
task(archiveRelease) {
    doLast {
        println 'archiveRelease task'
    }
}

build.finalizedBy release
archiveRelease.dependsOn build
release.dependsOn archiveRelease
```

So in that case `./gradlew build` & `./gradlew release` would be equivalent if that's what you want.

But if you want to have a standalone `release` task which would perform

- `./gradlew build` : build => archiveRelease => release
- `./gradlew release` : archiveRelease => release

gradle :

```
task(release) {
    doLast {
        println 'release task'
    }
}
task(archiveRelease) {
    doLast {
        println 'archiveRelease task'
    }
}

build.finalizedBy release
release.dependsOn archiveRelease
```